# WKwebview, js call to play an sound with Swift function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swift3

I want to build an function that plays an sound effect mixed though an javascript call.

**Problem**

In a WKWebView, we can't control the sound to be mixed in with music app like `Spotify`.

**Idea is to have an small function** in swift how to "listend" to an js call. So when I call the js function the app plays an sound effect that is mixed in with other background music.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to have function in your JS file, that not only contains your main functionality but also calls this little code:

```
...
if(window.webkit){
   window.webkit.messageHandlers["scriptHandler"].postMessage("ShouldPlaySound");
}
```

Then extend your swift controller with `WKScriptMessageHandler`. Set `webView.navigationDelegate` to this controller, and inside this controller create function:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    let messageBody:String = message.body as! String
    if(messageBody == "ShouldPlaySound"){
        // Play your sound
    }
}
```